# The minimum value of perimeter of the triangle

Tags: geometry, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, diophantine-equations

Let there be $\triangle ABC$ having integral side lengths such that angle $$ \angle A=3 \angle B $$ Then find the minimum value of its perimeter.

I did this with trigonometry and got an equation as: $$ 2p = 4b[2\cos^3( \theta) + \cos^2(\theta) - \cos(\theta)] $$ where $b$ = side opposite to $\angle B$, $\theta$ is the $\angle B $ and $p$ is half of the perimeter. How should I proceed?

Also show any other appropriate method.

Comment: $\theta$ is the angle at A, right? And the sides are integral, so there could be a way to use that.

Comment: Write $a/b$ and $c/b$ in terms of $\theta$.  Eliminate $\theta$ leaving a polynomial $p(a,b,c)=0$

Comment: @Empy2 could you please explain

Comment: @Richard theta is the angle B

Comment: Start with $a:b:c::\sin3\theta:\sin\theta:\sin(\pi-\theta-3\theta)$

Comment: @Empy2 ok... I have already found the ratio with the help of which I found the equation... I wrote a and c in terms of b and summed them up... If possible please write ur solution

Comment: It may be cheating, but Wikipedia _[integer triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_triangle)_ mentions this situation, "one angle three times another".

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: Good find!

Comment: Based on the wiki link, the minimum perimeter is $p=a+b+c=21$, with $(a,b,c)=(10,8,3)$.

Answer (score 3):

My try:

$$\frac{a}{\sin3\beta}=\frac{b}{\sin\beta}$$

$$\sin3\beta=3\sin\beta-4\sin^3\beta=\frac{a}{b}\sin\beta$$

$$3-4\sin^2\beta=\frac{a}{b}$$

$$\sin^2\beta=\frac14(3-\frac ab)\tag{1}$$

$$\frac{b}{\sin\beta}=\frac{c}{\sin4\beta}$$

$$\frac{\sin4\beta}{\sin\beta}=\frac{2\sin2\beta \cos2\beta}{\sin\beta}=4\cos\beta (1-2\sin^2\beta)=\frac cb$$

$$16\cos^2\beta(1-2\sin^2\beta)^2=\frac{c^2}{b^2}$$

$$16(1-\sin^2\beta)(1-2\sin^2\beta)^2=\frac{c^2}{b^2}\tag{2}$$

Replace (1) into (2) and after some simplifications you get:

$$\frac{a^3}{b^3}-\frac{a^2}{b^2}-\frac{a}{b}+1=\frac{c^2}{b^2}$$

$$a^3-a^2 b-a b^2+b^3=c^2b$$

$$(a+b)(a-b)^2=c^2 b$$

However I was not able to proceed and solve this equation, except by guessing. Obviously 10, 8 and 3 fit the equation (I have started with $a=b=1$)